# Vegas and database issue

Tags: javascript, php, json, vegasjs

I have a problem with `Vegas.js`. I'm trying to put images in from a database, but they are usually not displayed. Sometimes, only the first image is displayed once. However, if the images that I'm getting from the database are placed in a `<img>` tag, they are displayed properly, i also attached a screencap when i do a console.log of my JSON data. Here is my code :

```js
//JS
$.getJSON('ajax/Slides.php', function(slide) {
  $.each(slide, function(i,slides) {
    $('#slideMain').vegas (
      { slides: [{src: slides["path"]}] }
    );
  })
});

//However, if I do something like this, it shows me all the images:

    $('#slideMain').append('<img src="'+slide+'">');
```

```html
// PHP

#I have 3 columns in the DB(id,path,order),
#but i only need the path

#conexion to the database

public function showSlideModel($table)
{
    $stmt = conexion::connect()->prepare("SELECT path FROM $table ORDER BY order ASC");
    $stmt -> execute();
    return $stmt -> fetchAll();
    $stmt -> close();
}
    
#this is the controller

public function SlideController()
{
    $answer = SlideModel::showSlideModel("slides");

    foreach($answer as $row => $item) 
    {
        $slides[] = array('path'=>substr($item["path"], 6));
     }

      $jsonSlide = json_encode($slides);
      echo $jsonSlide;
}
        
// Ajax 

$slide = new Slider();
$slide ->SlideController();
echo $slide;
```

If someone could help me or let me know what I'm doing wrong, it will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance. Here is a screenshot of the console log: [image: JSON data console.log]

Comment: What does your database's structure look like? What does the query code look like and what do your results look like?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle with sample data? or can you provide us a sample code so we can check?

Comment: @AgiHammerthief,@NimeshkaSrimal, i edited my question and added the query for connecting to the db, i also attached a screen cap, when i do a console.log to the JSON data.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: It looks like you're using `path` as a key, but it doesn't exist in the row. You should be using `ruta` (as that property contains the path to the image) instead.

Comment: @AgiHammerthief i used 'ruta' is just that i have to translate the code to put it here